# Free RSS Aggregation between Windows and Mac

Tags: rss, newsreader

I recently purchased a MacBook to compliment my Windows desktop machine.  I am hunting around for a free RSS aggregator that I could use on both machines.  Currently I am using Google reader, but I miss the ability to preview articles before I navigate to them.  Additionally I do not want to manage two separate lists for each machine.  It does not matter to me if I use two different products for each OS, or an online product between the two.

Can anyone recommend a feature rich, free RSS aggregator that supports article previews that I can use in a Windows or Mac environment?

Answer (score 0):

If you click "Expanded" in the top right, you get something like what you want. But not just a snippet.

Another option is to use http://snackr.net/ and if you really feel excited you can tweak the code. This integrates with Google Reader, and is cross platform, which is nice. However, it isn't quite a passive as you would probably like. You will find it hard trying to find anything with a better feature set than Google Reader though.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[NewsBar](http://www.newsbar-app.com/)** for OS X - it will sync with your Google Reader account.

[image]

Comment: Looks nice.  Too bad it's Mac-only.